# Can I access an HTML table data using c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, selenium, coypu

Can I access the data of an HTML table using C#? 
I have to get the innerText of a `<td>` from C# (I can't use anything else).
Is there a simply way? Maybe using *[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)* or *[Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu)*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950337/retrieve-data-from-html-table-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, using selenium

```
IList<IWebElement> TRCollection = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tableId")).FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
IList<IWebElement> TDCollection;

foreach(IWebElement element in TRCollection )
{
//td list from each row
TDCollection = element.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

string column1 = TDCollection[0].Text;
...
}
```

Comment: if you need only table data from html and not all the process to enter the website you better use like @Alex Turcan said the Html Agility Pack. selenium is more for browser automation.

Comment: Uhm, I'm writing an autmation module.. and I need to confront my value with the one on the web page. What do you think, should I use selenium or HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: definitely selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Html Agility Pack is what i use when i need any data from a webpage. It is convenient because you get a tree similar to an XmlDocument, making it easy to "walk the tree" or to perform any kind of queries.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you have any example of "walking the tree". I'm not very familliar with HtmlAgilityPack  ...

Comment: It is very simple and straight forward. You can use XPATH to get what you need. Here's is a link with a more specific implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables